# Link in angularjs modal loads new page but links/scripts are disabled until page is manully refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So i created a modal pop up for one of my views with a link inside the modal. The link goes to another view however when the page is loaded, none of elements on the page are funtional(i.e such as the links). The only way to get the page to work is if I refresh the page manually. I added a  to see if that would work but it doesn't.

Does it have something to do with an http request?

```
<div class=" modal fade" id="win" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="cong modal-title">Congratulations <span ng-bind="name"></span>!</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="modal-body">

                          <a href="#/Success">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">NEXT</button>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">

         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What http request? you haven't provided any code. See [mcve]

Comment: Its just modal http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ pop up window with a link. Im Using ng-route for the views

Comment: Still not clear what the actual problem is. Should get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootsrap

Comment: Basically I have modal open up click and inside modal there is a button link.When I click the button link and it takes to the direct page but all my code written for that page doesn't work, such as the links and scripts.They only work until after I refresh that current page

Comment: So what errors are thrown? Where's the code for that page? Why are you showing modal when problem is there?